# Trouble playing audio on second ESP32 core

Tags: audio, arduino, esp32

I'm trying to build a web radio with a TFT display and an I2S audio decoder. But I can't run the audio. copy function on core 2. The reason I want to run it on Core 2 is so that I can have the audio playing and still be able to run other bits of code.

Here is the full sketch:

```
//==================================================================================================
//
// Internet Radio based on the radio-browser API
//
//==================================================================================================

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h>
#include "SPI.h"
#include <SdFat.h>
#include <Adafruit_ImageReader.h>
#include "AudioTools.h"
#include "AudioCodecs/CodecMP3Helix.h"

#include "definitions.h"

SemaphoreHandle_t xMutex;
TaskHandle_t audioTask;
void audio_loop(void * parameter);

SdFat                SD_fat;
Adafruit_ImageReader reader(SD_fat);
Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

I2SStream i2s;
EncodedAudioStream decoder(&i2s, new MP3DecoderHelix());
StreamCopy audioSD; 
File audioFile;

#include "definitions.h"

void setup() {;
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!SD_fat.begin(SD_CS, SD_SCK_MHZ(10))) {
    Serial.println("SD card initialization failed!");
    for(;;); // Fatal error, do not continue
  }
  Serial.println("SD card initialized!");

  AudioLogger::instance().begin(Serial, AudioLogger::Info); 

  // setup i2s
  auto config = i2s.defaultConfig(TX_MODE);
  config.pin_bck = I2S_BCLK;
  config.pin_ws = I2S_LRC;
  config.pin_data = I2S_DOUT;
  i2s.begin(config);

  // setup I2S based on sampling rate provided by decoder
  decoder.setNotifyAudioChange(i2s);
  decoder.begin();

  xMutex = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();

  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(audio_loop, "audioloop", 50000, NULL, 1, &audioTask, 0);

  tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
}

void play_audio(const char *filename) {
  audioFile = SD_fat.open(filename, FILE_READ);
  audioSD.begin(decoder, audioFile);
}

void audio_loop(void * parameter) {
  for (;;) {
    Serial.println("Before xSemaphoreTake");
    if (xSemaphoreTake(xMutex, portMAX_DELAY)) {
      audioSD.copy();
      Serial.println("After audioSD.copy()");
      xSemaphoreGive(xMutex);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  radio_functions();
  joystick_functions();
}

void radio_functions() {

  if(radio_intro_played == false && APP_RADIO == true) {

    reader.drawBMP("/app_radio/radio_intro.bmp", tft, 0, 0);
    play_audio("/app_radio/radio_intro.mp3");
    radio_intro_played = true;
    menu_started = false;
    SHOW_MENU = 1;
    prev_arrow_pos[SHOW_MENU] = 0;
  }

  if(APP_RADIO == true && SHOW_MENU == 1 && !audioSD.copy()) {

    if(!menu_started) {
      arrow = return_last_pos();
      slider = 0;
      MAX_arrow = 4;
      MAX_slider = 0;
      arrow_disabled = false;
      slider_disabled = true;
      slider_no_delay = false;
      joystick_standby = true;
      reader.drawBMP("/app_radio/radio_main_menu.bmp", tft, 0, 0);
    }

    if(!joystick_standby && menu_started || !menu_started) {
      reader.drawBMP("/app_radio/radio_main_menu.bmp", tft, 0, 0);
      if(arrow == 0) {
        tft.drawRoundRect(0,27,126,26,3,ST77XX_GREEN);
        tft.drawRoundRect(0,26,127,28,3,ST77XX_GREEN);
      } else if(arrow == 1) {
        tft.drawRoundRect(0,54,115,26,3,ST77XX_GREEN);
        tft.drawRoundRect(0,53,116,28,3,ST77XX_GREEN);
      } else if(arrow == 2) {
        tft.drawRoundRect(0,78,106,26,3,ST77XX_GREEN);
        tft.drawRoundRect(0,77,107,28,3,ST77XX_GREEN);
      } else if(arrow == 3) {
        tft.drawRoundRect(0,104,91,26,3,ST77XX_GREEN);
        tft.drawRoundRect(0,103,92,28,3,ST77XX_GREEN);
      } else if(arrow == 4) {
        tft.drawRoundRect(0,134,59,26,3,ST77XX_GREEN);
        tft.drawRoundRect(0,133,60,27,3,ST77XX_GREEN);
      }
      play_audio("/global/select.mp3");
      joystick_standby = true;
    }
    menu_started = true;
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Before xSemaphoreTake
After audioSD.copy()
Before xSemaphoreTake
After audioSD.copy()
Before xSemaphoreTake
After audioSD.copy()
Before xSemaphoreTake
After audioSD.copy()
Before xSemaphoreTake
After audioSD.copy()
Before xSemaphoreTake
After audioSD.copy()
Before xSemaphoreTake
After audioSD.copy()
Before xSemaphoreTake
After audioSD.copy()
Before xSemaphoreTake
After audioSD.copy()
[I] StreamCopy.h : 74 - Before xSemaphoreTake
buffer_size=1024

assert failed: xQueueGenericSend queue.c:832 (pxQueue->pcHead != ((void *)0) || pxQueue->u.xSemaphore.xMutexHolder == ((void *)0) || pxQueue->u.xSemaphore.xMutexHolder == xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle())


Backtrace: 0x400836f5:0x3ffc7d00 0x40089e9d:0x3ffc7d20 0x4008ee05:0x3ffc7d40 0x4008a6e2:0x3ffc7e70 0x400dfcad:0x3ffc7eb0 0x400d7306:0x3ffc7ed0 0x400d90f9:0x3ffc7ef0 0x400d89a2:0x3ffc7f10 0x400d8e05:0x3ffc7f30 0x400d8e5c:0x3ffc7f50 0x40128647:0x3ffc7f70 0x400d91a1:0x3ffc7f90 0x400d79b4:0x3ffc7fb0 0x400d25bc:0x3ffc7fe0 0x400de9a9:0x3ffc8010 0x400de9d1:0x3ffc8030 0x4012782d:0x3ffc8050 0x401278de:0x3ffc8070 0x400d4ab8:0x3ffc8090 0x400d53f2:0x3ffc80d0 0x400d5563:0x3ffc8100 0x400e0a31:0x3ffc8120




ELF file SHA256: f316367772fa5939

Rebooting...
```

I'm rather new to this area of Arduino so any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I made it a little less complex and cleaned it up:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h>
#include "SPI.h"
#include <SdFat.h>
#include <Adafruit_ImageReader.h>
#include "AudioTools.h"
#include "AudioCodecs/CodecMP3Helix.h"


//------------------------------------------ SPI

#define SPI_MOSI 23  //DATA Out
#define SPI_MISO 19  //DATA Out
#define SPI_SCLK 18  //Serial Clock

#define SD_CS    2   //Chip select for SD

#define TFT_CS   13  //Chip select for TFT
#define TFT_RST  12  //Reset for TFT
#define TFT_DC   14  //Data/Command for TFT

//------------------------------------------ I2S

#define I2S_DOUT  25
#define I2S_BCLK  27
#define I2S_LRC   26

//------------------------------------------ Variables

bool radio_intro_played = false;
bool audio_playing = false;


SemaphoreHandle_t xMutex;
TaskHandle_t audioTask;

SdFat                SD_fat;
Adafruit_ImageReader reader(SD_fat);
Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

I2SStream i2s;
EncodedAudioStream decoder(&i2s, new MP3DecoderHelix());
StreamCopy audioSD; 
File audioFile;

void audio_loop(void * parameter) {
  for (;;) {
    Serial.println("Before xSemaphoreTake");
    if (xSemaphoreTake(xMutex, portMAX_DELAY)) {
      if(!audioSD.copy())
      {
        audio_playing = true;
      } else {
        audio_playing = false;
      }
      xSemaphoreGive(xMutex);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {;
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!SD_fat.begin(SD_CS, SD_SCK_MHZ(10))) {
    Serial.println("SD card initialization failed!");
    for(;;); // Fatal error, do not continue
  }
  Serial.println("SD card initialized!");

  AudioLogger::instance().begin(Serial, AudioLogger::Info); 

  // setup i2s
  auto config = i2s.defaultConfig(TX_MODE);
  config.pin_bck = I2S_BCLK;
  config.pin_ws = I2S_LRC;
  config.pin_data = I2S_DOUT;
  i2s.begin(config);

  // setup I2S based on sampling rate provided by decoder
  decoder.setNotifyAudioChange(i2s);
  decoder.begin();

  xMutex = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();

  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(audio_loop, "audioloop", 50000, NULL, 1, &audioTask, 0);

  tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
}

void play_audio(const char *filename) {
  audioFile = SD_fat.open(filename, FILE_READ);
  audioSD.begin(decoder, audioFile);
}

void loop() {
  radio_functions();
}

void radio_functions() {

  if(radio_intro_played == false) {

    reader.drawBMP("/app_radio/radio_intro.bmp", tft, 0, 0);
    play_audio("/app_radio/radio_intro.mp3");
    radio_intro_played = true;
  }
}
```

And here is its output:

```
E (13476) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time:
E (13476) task_wdt:  - IDLE (CPU 0)
E (13476) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (13476) task_wdt: CPU 0: audioloop
E (13476) task_wdt: CPU 1: loopTask
E (13476) task_wdt: Aborting.

abort() was called at PC 0x400e9831 on core 0


Backtrace: 0x400836f5:0x3ffbed5c |<-CORRUPTED




ELF file SHA256: 7358597823cb43ff

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
```

Comment: I see some rather strange initialization and task flow there. Firstly you launch the `audio_loop()` before you've initialized the streams with `play_audio(const char *filename)` - are you sure the library accepts this? Secondly you call `audioSD.copy()` from two different tasks, one of them protected by a mutex, the other not - this is very likely a problem for the library and the cause of your crash. Looks sketchy to me.

Comment: @Tarmo Okay, the `audioSD.copy` the second time is a mistake on my end, sorry about that. I'll make the changes and recompile. the sketchiness is me attempting to learn the ropes.